# How can multiple developers develope one slack app?

Tags: slack

I'm developing a slack app with a collegue and we couldn't understand how can both of us develop the server at once.

We're working in socket mode, using Slack-bolt for Python. Each of us has a local copy of the server, and when both local servers are up, just one server gets all the requests from the Slack client.

What is the common practise to allow both of us to develop the server at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Well, every developer should work independently by coding in local and deploying once it's working. So in the main server, you have to use a proper endpoint(not local) in slack bot settings and thus on installing that app both devs can use the app and check it.